# Using T-SQL to convert Table to HTML, handling NULL issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;

SET @tableHTML =
    N'<H1>Report Heading</H1>' +
    N'<table border="1">' +
    N'<th>Check Number</th>' +
    N'<th>Last Operator Date</th>' +
    N'<th>Last Timestamp</th>' +
    N'<th>Run Date</th>' +
    N'<th>Issued Check Number</th>' +
    N'<th>Error Description</th>' +
    '<tr>' +
    CAST ( ( SELECT td = S.CHK_NUM,       '',
                    td = S.LAST_OPER_ID, '',
                    td = S.LAST_TIMESTMP, '',
                    td = S.RUN_DT, '',
                    td = ISNULL(S.RE_ISSUE_CHK_NUM,-1), '',
                    td = ISNULL(S.ERR_DESC,'<null>'), ''
              FROM STAGNG_CDDP_ERR_RCD S
              FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
    N'</table>' ;

PRINT @tableHTML
```

If I attempt to substiture -1 with a varchar literal '(Null)', I get the error

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Null' to data type int.
```

I would prefer to display  if the RE_ISSUE_CHK_NUM is null, but that field is an int and i believe the "TYPE" param is forcing teh returned value to match the original column's type.

How do I modify the output so all of teh columns are text and hence formattable?

**Edit**

When I try this...

```
DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;

SET @tableHTML =
    N'<H1>Report Heading</H1>' +
    N'<table border="1">' +
    N'<th>Check Number</th>' +
    N'<th>Last Operator Date</th>' +
    N'<th>Last Timestamp</th>' +
    N'<th>Run Date</th>' +
    N'<th>Issued Check Number</th>' +
    N'<th>Error Description</th>' +
    '<tr>' +
    CAST ( ( SELECT td = S.CHK_NUM,       '',
                    td = S.LAST_OPER_ID, '',
                    td = S.LAST_TIMESTMP, '',
                    td = S.RUN_DT, '',
                    --td = ISNULL(S.RE_ISSUE_CHK_NUM,-1), '',
                    td = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(16), ISNULL(S.RE_ISSUE_CHK_NUM,'(Null)')), '',
                    td = ISNULL(S.ERR_DESC,'<null>'), ''
              FROM STAGNG_CDDP_ERR_RCD S
              FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
    N'</table>' ;

PRINT @tableHTML
```

I get this:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '(Null)' to data type int.
```

It's tthe Check Number field that is Null that is numeric that i would like to display the string 'Null' in the HTML.

Is it the `TYPE` param that is the issue?

Comment: To create a HTML email report.

Comment: As shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx

Comment: SQL is not a good tool for this. Html is more than just concatenating things - there are important escaping rules too. And inportantly, html is not xml. IMO the only correct thing to do here is to use SQL to get the *data*, and build the report in a different layer (say, a .net app, but any platform would do). SQL is not a general purpose programming language.

Comment: @Marc: I tend to agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line

```
td = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(16), ISNULL(S.RE_ISSUE_CHK_NUM,'(Null)')), '',
```

to

```
td = CASE WHEN S.RE_ISSUE_CHK_NUM IS NULL THEN '<NULL>' ELSE  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(16), S.RE_ISSUE_CHK_NUM) END , '',
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I attempt to substiture -1 with a varchar literal '(Null)', I get the error
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Null' to data type int.

I suspect this error is occurring for the following line:

```
td = ISNULL(S.ERR_DESC,'<null>'),
```

If you want to display `-1` when `S.ERR_DESC` is null, then you can put it in quotes as follows:

```
td = ISNULL(S.ERR_DESC,'-1'),
```

> How do I modify the output so all of teh columns are text and hence formattable?

You can `CONVERT` non-text columns to `NVARCHAR`.

e.g.

```
td = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(16), ISNULL(S.RE_ISSUE_CHK_NUM,-1)), '',
```